# highlighting time in text

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string: `Something 8:45 foo bar foo bar at 23:50`

How to highlight and mark with `<b>` tag all time combinations in string like 8:45 and 23:50?
As a result I want to have `Something <b>8:45</b> foo bar foo bar at <b>23:50</b>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
"Something 8:45 foo bar foo bar at 23:50".gsub(/\d{1,2}:\d{2}/).each {|hour| hour = "<b>#{hour}<b>" }
```

Identify hours and replace each one with `<b>hour<b>`

Comment: You don't need the `each`, `gsub` can take a block. But you don't really need that either, since it can be done directly inside the `gsub` (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

```
>> "Something 8:45 foo bar foo bar at 23:50".gsub(/\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}\b/, '<b>\0</b>') 
#=> "Something <b>8:45</b> foo bar foo bar at <b>23:50</b>"
```

Edit: if you need to, you can make the regex check for correct times, but I didn't bother for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex `/((2[0-3])|(1[0-9])|(0?[0-9])):([0-5]?[0-9])/` to match, as it also checks if the time is in correct format

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with this regex, so it got a downvote

Comment: I'd say the `?` in the first digit of the minutes, since nobody writes 13:4 pm, for example. I like that you restricted the regexp to only match valid times.

Answer (score -1):

easy

replace ([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}) with '**$1**'

Comment: That just returns the same string. Using parentheses and `$1` is redundant. Use `$0` instead.